# Unable to create partition on a free space (The location xxxxxxxxx is outside of the device /dev/sdb)

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I have an unusual stuff here. I have plugged in my USB which is 8G of storage. And the `gnome-disks` utility can see that there are free space as shown bellow:

[image: Free 7.8 space]

But when I try to create a FAT32/NTFS partition, I get an error bellow :
[image: Error when creating partition]

> Error creating partition on /dev/sdb: Command-line `parted --align optimal --script "/dev/sdb" "mkpart primary ext2 1MiB 7750287359b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: The location 7750287359b is outside of the device /dev/sdb.
>    (udisks-error-quark, 0)

More troubling is the fact that when I use `gparted` to try to resize th thumb drive, I get something like this where `gparted` can only see that my USB drive has **1.8G** of space:
[image: only 1.8G of space]

So what can I do to reclaim my space ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wiping the whole USB with **dd** : `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`
 and deleted all with 
`sudo gdisk /dev/sdb` ( = launch `gdisk`, then type `x`, then type `e`, then type `w` to save your changes).